# Django - Admin - Applying 'label_suffix' for Models

Tags: django, django-admin, django-forms

Is to possible to configure 'label_suffix' other than (:) for all the models in my admin site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a subclass of the `django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin` class which sets the `ModelAdmin.form`'s `label_suffix` to a set string. That way any model which used that `ModelAdmin` would have the same prefix:

```
# myproject/myapp/admin.py

from django.contrib import admin
from myproject.myapp.models import MyModel, AnotherModel, YetAnotherModel, \
                                   SomeSpecialModel

class PrefixAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PrefixAdmin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.form.label_suffix = 'some suffix here'

# Use this ModelAdmin class for all your models:

admin.site.register(MyModel, PrefixAdmin)
admin.site.register(AnotherModel, PrefixAdmin)
admin.site.register(YetAnotherModel, PrefixAdmin)

# Or if you need a specific ModelAdmin for a particular Model
# just extend from the PrefxiAdmin class:

class SpecialModelAdmin(PrefixAdmin):
    # ...

admin.site.register(SomeSpecialModel, SpecialModelAdmin)
```

Comment: This seems to be have no effect. Am I missing something other than the code mentioned here? Receiving the following error while trying to print. "type object 'ModelForm' has no attribute 'label_suffix'"

Comment: I can verify that a `django.forms.Form` has the attribute `label_suffix` however looking through Django's source code I see that `ModelForm` extends from something else. On top of that I cannot see a way of getting a `Form` object from a `ModelForm`. I am a bit stuck to be honest.

Comment: Backwards incompatible changes in 1.6; BoundField.label_tag now includes the form’s label_suffix https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/releases/1.6/#boundfield-label-tag-now-includes-the-form-s-label-suffix

Answer (score 0):

`label_suffix` doesn't work for Django Admin model forms because the suffix ':' is fixed into the code (see `django/contrib/admin/helpers.py`).